# Is there any SMS through data app that is available for iPhone and Blackberry?

Tags: iphone, blackberry, sdk, sms, message

I know there's the app called Ping! for iPhone that allows the sending of SMS messages over your 3G connection, therefore it doesn't count as a text message and it acts pretty much the same as the regular iPhone texting software. Is there any app like this that's available for both iPhones and Blackberrries?

Answer (score 2):

Google Voice allows you to send and receive messages through a web frontend. Because it is just a web page, it should work on any phone with a data plan. More info here: http://www.google.com/googlevoice/about.html